# allow_dynamic_fields: true' (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Strange error occuring at server start , please look at logs

```
    umair-2:game-minion umairejaz$ rails server
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/script_rails_loader.rb:11: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:136: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
    Could not load SystemTimer >= v1.2.0. Falling back to timeout.rb. SystemTimer is STRONGLY recommended for timeouts in Ruby 1.8.7. See http://ph7spot.com/blog/system-timer-1-2-release for details.
    => Booting WEBrick
    => Rails 3.0.7 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
    => Call with -d to detach
    => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    Exiting
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load': syntax error on line 1, col 24: `      allow_dynamic_fields: true' (ArgumentError)
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongoid-2.0.0.beta.20/lib/mongoid/railtie.rb:53
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
        from /Users/umairejaz/Projects/game-minion/config/environment.rb:5
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from /Users/umairejaz/Projects/game-minion/config.ru:3
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
        from /Users/umairejaz/Projects/game-minion/config.ru:1:in `new'
        from /Users/umairejaz/Projects/game-minion/config.ru:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check any of your YAML files under the config folder, specifically one that has the `allow_dynamic_fields` setting in it. It's likely an error either above, below, or on that particular line. Remove any extraneous whitespace and reformat things (i.e. either use tabs or spaces, not both). Check for any other clutter or extraneous keywords.